# Java: Lucene indexing empty _0.fdt and _0.fdx file with size 0kb

Tags: java, lucene

i have browse the internet for this but i cant seem to search with the right term.
My problem is with Lucene indexing empty _0.fdt and _0.fdx file with size 0kb. This means it didnt index my data.

**Here is my code:**

```
private int indexDocs(String dataTmp){
    // LETS START PROCESSING THE INDEXING OF CONTENTS OF THE DATA PASSED
    // make a new, empty document
    Document doc = new Document();
    // Method variables
    int trueValue=0;
    String[] datas;
    String[][] contents;
    String[] contentArray;
    // Setting single variable
    String field="";
    String inContent="";
    long time;

    // NOW LETS PROCESS
    datas=dataReader(dataTmp); // Calling the data reader
    contents=dataProcessor(datas); // Calling the contents retriever
    // Now lets index each content retrieved
    if(contents.length>0){
        for(String[] content:contents){
            // Now lets loop through each content to index
            for(int i=0; i<content.length; i++){
                contentArray=content[i].split("\\::::");
                field=contentArray[0];
                inContent=contentArray[1];
                //System.out.println(field+" === "+inContent);
                // NOW LETS INDEX DOCUMENT IN ITS APPROPRAITE FIELD
                if(field.equals("contents") || field.equals("title") || field.equals("keywords")){
                    Field textField=new TextField(field, inContent, Field.Store.YES);
                    doc.add(textField);
                }
                else{
                    Field stringField = new StringField(field, inContent, Field.Store.YES);
                    doc.add(stringField);
                }

            } // End of loop
        } // End of loop

        // Here we try to index Date of time the index was logged
        time=System.currentTimeMillis();
        doc.add(new LongPoint("date", time));

        // New index, so we just add the document (no old document can be there):
        // System.out.println("adding " + file);
        try {
             //by a reader on the same index
            writer.addDocument(doc);
            // Now lets set the true
            trueValue=1;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } // End of content check

    // Now lets return value
    return trueValue;
}
```

I dont know am doing wrong to get this kind of output file. I've index data with lucene before but i cant just see my problem with the code.
I am trying to loop through contents in an array and index individually but am getting no index record. Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: The below answer worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know where you have declared writer but this happens generally  when writer is not closed ,try closing writer after adding the document

Comment: I had the following:
 writer.addDocument(doc);
which was giving zero byte files as above. Closing the writr after produces a valid index.
writer.close();
I could not find this issue except in this SO post.
Thanks a lot..